# Fancybox not working properly on Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, fancybox

I have trouble using Fancybox 3 with rails 5. My goal is to embed a  responsive Iframe but after hours of tests, I didn't manage to make it work.

According to the documentation, if I want to insert an Iframe, I should write this :

```
<a data-fancybox data-type="iframe" data-src="http://codepen.io/fancyapps/full/jyEGGG/" href="javascript:;">
Webpage
</a>
```

With this code, when I click on the link, nothing happens. I'm pretty sure here that there is a problem with ruby and rails structure because when I put some javascript above in my view, the fancybox launches BUT returns me this error into the box : "The requested content cannot be loaded. Please try again later."

Here's my almost working code with javascript and HTML in my view :

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
  var fancybox = function(){
    $('.fancybox').fancybox({ 
        iframe: {
            css: {
                width: '100%',
                height: '100%',
            }
        }
    });         
};
$(document).on("page:load ready", fancybox);
```

```
<a class="fancybox" data-fancybox data-type="iframe" data-src="https://spaces.archilogic.com/3d/!02e31ca5-41c2-4a7f-a25d-601810a7c85a?mode=view&amp;main-menu=interior&amp;view-menu=none&amp;presentation=loop" href="javascript:;">
    <h1>TITLE</h1>
</a>
```

Finally, I managed to get the Iframe to work by doing this BUT it calculates the Iframe size at page loading and never moves again if the browser is set to a different size :

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
  jQuery(function() {
    $("#visite3d").fancybox({
            width   : '100%',
            height  : '100%',
  });
});
```

```
<a id="visite3d" class="iframe" href="https://spaces.archilogic.com/3d/!02e31ca5-41c2-4a7f-a25d-601810a7c85a?mode=view&amp;main-menu=interior&amp;view-menu=none&amp;presentation=loop">
    <h1>Visite 3D</h1>
</a>
```

So, anyone know why fancybox's Iframe isn't working as it should when I insert the simple HTML provided in the doc ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

fancyBox does not care if you are using RoR, Wordpress, Laravel, [put any name here], just follow simple steps - make sure that required files are loaded, code executes in correct order and your content is accessible. That's it.

Since you have not provided any demo/test page, there is no way to help you.